# OJS (Open Journal System) theme development

Tags: themes, system, journal, ojs

I want to develop my own theme for ojs.

I took an existing theme (plugin/themes) and updated only names of files and variables that suits w.r.t my environment. I was expecting display of my theme name in the list "Setup=>The Look->5.6 Journal Layout" but no luck. I am getting a fatal error.

`Fatal error: Class 'SteelThemePlugin' not found in C:\wamp\www\jucs\plugins\themes\shahid\index.php on line 23`

I googled for this issue and for developing abstract guideline. However, I cannot find any useful tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find enough detail no problem, Read the following steps you will be able to figure it out.

1. All the themes are placed inside the `plugin/themes` directory.
2. Thus create your theme folder say `pakistan`.
3. Now you will have to create the following files:

   3.1. `version.xml`

   3.2. `index.php`

   3.3. `PakistanThemePlugin.inc.php`

   3.4. `pakistan.css`

---

**NOTE:** The easiest way to start with is to copy any existing theme and starting start changing its values that suites you.

Your own custom theme is ready and you can use OJS with same theme as your parent site.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you've forgotten to change the class name in the index.php wrapper. Ensure that the require_once statement there and the return statement reference your updated theme class name.